# Problem with retrieving an image

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

following problem:

I created a NSXMLParser subclass to get Xbox Live profile data, the class works fine but i have a problem with displaying an image.

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[xbl.games objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @"Image64Url"]);
```

output:

```
http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/+4/R1/1Wdsb2JhbC9ECgUAGwEfV1oiL2ljb24vMC84MDAwAAAAAAAAAPpahOQ=.jpg
```

displaying the image:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[xbl.games objectAtIndex: i] objectForKey: @"Image64Url"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
gamerPicView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Does not work, but if i run:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://tiles.xbox.com/tiles/+4/R1/1Wdsb2JhbC9ECgUAGwEfV1oiL2ljb24vMC84MDAwAAAAAAAAAPpahOQ=.jpg"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
gamerPicView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Its working, im really confused whats my mistake?
Thanks for help and greetings from switzerland.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would print what 'url' is after your first (unsuccessful) attempt at displaying the image and see if it is the same URL or not as the code that works, since this seems like the only place something could be wrong.

Edit: And if you still can't figure out the problem, post the NSLog output for 'url' in both cases.

Comment: Thanks, in the output of the url is a "\n" i have no idea why, but if i cut it out all works fine. Thanks again.